# Enterprise architect addin not getting Loaded

Tags: enterprise, enterprise-architect

I created a class library in C# for addinn  and my Enterprise architect is loading it in Extensions but when I create a WPF application and change its output type to library but Enterprise architect is not able to load this library.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and restate your question.

Comment: I guess that's a WPF issue then and you should dig there.

Answer (score 0):

EA only reads ddl's as add-in that have an addin-class exposed to COM. 
I'm guessing switching to WPF messed up the COM registration of your add-in class.
Some more info on writing add-ins for EA on my [website](http://bellekens.com/writing-ea-add-ins/)

Comment: Yes Bellekens its works fine when I create a c# project of class library type and making it  COM Visible, registering  the assembly for COM Interop and and creating registry key for it. But problem comes when I create a wpf application and set its output type to class library and repeat all the above steps then my addin is not getting Loaded in EA and under manage addins I am founding it as missing status.This I want to do because I want to include wpf window insted of older windows forms.

Comment: or Is there any way to add WPF window to class library

Comment: I don't know enough of WPF to answer that, but you are not obligated to have only one project. Why don't you create a regular class library project for the add-in class, and a WPF project for your GUI? Then reference the WPF project in your add-in project.